# Finding emacs release notes

Tags: help

What's the best source of emacs release notes - especially for reading prior to installing an update?

I searched Google for "emacs release notes". There are some posts about specific releases (and some, [like this about Emacs 25.1](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/whats-new-in-emacs-25-1), are really good), but no definitive source.

There's another question on this site which discusses [what's new in Emacs 25](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/what-are-the-major-features-planned-for-gnu-emacs-25). The answers and comments there point to some source locations - are those generalizable?

Answer (score 3):

The Emacs NEWS file is the "history of user-visible changes."

The NEWS file on the emacs master git branch shows the latest in development http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/NEWS. As of this writing, it shows features planned for Emacs 26.1

If you need release notes for an earlier version, browse the [etc](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/etc/) directory for files like `NEWS.25`, `NEWS.24`, etc.

Alternately, browse starting at the [top of the repository](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/), click on one branch (e.g. `emacs-25` and navigate to `etc/NEWS` to see the news of that branch.

Comment: You can open the NEWS file from Emacs with `C-h n`.

Comment: Ah, good hint - but doesn't help with reading release notes prior to download and installing.

Comment: You can use the [GitHub Emacs mirror](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/tree/master/etc) to browse `NEWS` files, or download them individually and read them in Emacs using `outline-mode`/`org-mode`.

Comment: Also mentioned in [an answer to the linked question](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7187/5296): http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/news

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>C-n</kbd> makes things pretty straightforward if a particular release is of interest.

For example, try `C-u` `C-h` `C-n` and then enter "25.1" to review the NEWS.25 file content.